# how to get params[:id] of @post when you have layout: false

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails and want to create a model where every `post#show` comes into a bootstrap-modal not into a separate `show.html.erb` page.

In my `show` method I have something like this:

```
def show 
  @confessions = Confession.find(params[:id])
  @comment = Confessioncomment.where(confession_id: @confessions).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5).order('created_at ASC')
end
```

I am getting my `@confessions` from the `params[:id]` as of now to show the exact post I clicked on, but what I want is not to show a separate show page but to load everything in my bootstrap-modal on the same page.

I know I can use `layout :false` to tell that show will have no layout but I am not sure how to use it, or if there is any other way to do this.

How can I show post on same page rather than loading a new page from controller.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Don't load it through the rails view renderer. Instead, do an AJAX call from within your JavaScript code and before loading the bootstrap modal hit the endpoint/route to pull the record but return it as json:

```
def show 
  @confessions = Confession.find(params[:id])
  @comment = Confessioncomment.where(confession_id: @confessions).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5).order('created_at ASC')

  render json: @confessions, status: 200
end
```

Then use that json response on your JS to dynamically load the modal.

You probably also want to return just one instance model for confession and pull the comments from its relation like: `@confession.comments` but you'll need to set up your models properly. That will make your rendering much easier than having to use two different instance variables.

Comment: thanks for the advise... i will try this and see if it works.. :)

Comment: could you do me a favor ? can you explain how can I use that JSON returned in my javascript code to create a view from data returned by @confessions .. 

it will be a great help.. thanks

Comment: @AlaapDhall well you could use just like jQuery + Bootstrap to build up dynamically the modal and then catch the success handler. Try to search here on stackoverflow for examples, there should be many. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

in the confessions list/table

```
<%= link_to @confession.title, @confession, remote: true %>
```

in your controller

```
def show 
  @confessions = Confession.find(params[:id])
  @comment = Confessioncomment.where(confession_id: @confessions).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5).order('created_at ASC')

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

create a file show.js.erb with the following content

```
$('#dynamically_filled').find('.modal-dialog:first').html("<%=j render('confession') %>");
$('#dynamically_filled').modal();
```

add this in the top of show.html.erb

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

the content of _confession.html.erb must context the rest

```
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title"><%= @confession.title %></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p><%= @confession.content %></p>
  </div>
</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
```

Answer (score 0):

First, Layout false is not what you are thinking...

Rails works with some default behavior. Every route of your application will call a view with that same name even if there is no method definition in your controller.

If you wan't to render another template with any method you will have to call a render function at end of it.

```
def show 
  @confessions = Confession.find(params[:id])
  @comment = Confessioncomment.where(confession_id: @confessions).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5).order('created_at ASC')
  render 'another/page', layout: false
end
```

What I tell rails with that code is to render template from that path 'another/page' with layout false.

Now I tell you what is layout false.

Your brand new project comes with an application.htlm.erb layout that yields every other page of your app. Sometimes you don't want to a page be yielded by that layout, so you apply layout false, or layout: 'another/layout'.